# mongodb single node performance

Tags: mongodb, grails

I use MongoDB for an internal ADMIN type of application used by my team.
Mongo is installed on 1 box and no replica sets.
ADMIN application inserts `70K to 100K` documents/per day and we maintain 4 months of data. DB has `~100 million` documents at any given time.
When the application was deployed, it all started fine for few days. As the data kept accumulated to reach the 4 months max limit, I see severe performance issues with MongoDB.
I installed `MongoDB 3.0.4` as-is on a Linux box and did not fine tune any optimization settings.

**Are there any optimization settings I need to adjust?**
ADMIN application has schedulers which runs every 1/2 hr to insert and purge outdated data. Given below collection with indexes defined on createdDate,env,messageId,sourceSystem, I see few queries were taking `30 min` to respond.
Sample query: *Count of documents with a given env,sourceSystem, but between a given range of dates.*
 ADMIN app uses `grails` and the above query is created using GORM. It used to work fine in the beginning. But over the period of time, performance degraded. I tried restarting the application as well. It didn't help. I believe using the MongoDB as-is (like a Dev Mode) might be causing performance issue. Any suggestions on what to tweak in settings (perhaps cpu/mem limits etc)?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5575e388e4b001976b5e570f"),
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2015-06-07T05:00:34.040Z"),
    "env" : "prod",
    "messageId" : "f684b34d-a480-42a0-a7b8-69d6d18f39e5",
    "payload" : "JSON or XML DATA",
    "sourceSystem" : "sourceModule"
}
```

**Update:**

Indices:

```
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "admin.Message"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "messageId" : 1
                },
                "name" : "messageId_1",
                "ns" : "admin.Message"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "createdDate" : 1
                },
                "name" : "createdDate_1",
                "ns" : "admin.Message"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "sourceSystem" : 1
                },
                "name" : "sourceSystem_1",
                "ns" : "admin.Message"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "env" : 1
                },
                "name" : "env_1",
                "ns" : "admin.Message"
        }
]
```

Comment: First thought was to see if using indexes appropriately could yield a performance gain. For example on the fields that you use frequently (selected fields to purge data, etc.). You are using index on each field or on the group of fields?

Comment: Indexes are defined per field and not as a group. Delete query works env and createdDate fields

Comment: Could you try to see an explain plan or similar? If MongoDB provides something like this. Can you maybe if you know whether it is a write performance issue or a delete performance issue? Also how big is your data (does it fit into physical memory)?

Comment: Please edit the question and show us the indices as per output of `db.yourCollection.getIndices()` and your queries. Please also state the amount of RAM available and free. A gradual degradation of performance usually indicates bad indices or lack of RAM